# Question about representation theory of the symmetric group

Tags: finite-groups, modules, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $G=\mathfrak{S}_3=\langle (12),(23)\rangle$, the symmetric group on $3$ letters, $k$ a field and $V$ the "standard module", $V=\langle v_1, v_2, v_3 \rangle$ and the group algebra $A=k[G]$.

If the characteristic of $k$ doesn't divide $|G|$, we can write $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$ with $V_1=\langle v_1+v_2+v_3 \rangle$ and $V_2=\langle (v_1-v_2), (v_2-v_3) \rangle$ i.e. $\{v_1-v_2, v_2-v_3\}$ is a basis for the orthogonal complement $V_1$ of $V$.

$\mathfrak{S}_3$ acts on $k^3$ by permuting the coordinates of a column vector: $\rho_g(v_i)=v_{g(v_i)}$.

$V_1$ is a $\mathfrak{S}_3$-invariant subspace of $V$; its complement $V_1^{\perp}=V_2$ can be defined as the kernel of the projection of $V$ onto $V_1$:
\begin{equation}
V_2=\{(a, b, c) \}\: | \: a+b+c=0 \}.
\end{equation}

If characteristic of $k$ is $3$, then we need to find a basis of $V$ to exhibit the following chain called a $\textbf{flag}$ (fixed by $G$):

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle V_1=\langle v_1+v_2+v_3 \rangle \subset V_2=\langle v_1+v_2+v_3, v_1-v_2 \rangle \subset V
\end{equation}

Seeing this chain of inclusions, we can think of a basis for $V$ written as $\{v_1+v_2+v_3, v_1-v_2, \bullet \bullet \bullet \}$ but I can't see why this particular basis of $V$ works.

Hope my question makes sense ! I'm not really sure about that ! Positive characteristic is a complicated subject.
I thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: If you're just asking what the third vector $x$ should be in a basis $\{v_1+v_2+v_3,v_1-v_2,x\}$ of $V$, then the answer is that any vector outside your $V_2$ will work, for instance $v_1$. If you're asking something else, then please clarify the question.

Comment: Andreas Blass: I don't understand why (in characteristic 3), the second and the third vector of the basis of $V$ are respectively $v_1-v_2$ and $v_1$.

Comment: The second vector was chosen carefully, so that it and the first vector generate an **invariant 2-dimensional** subspace $V_2$. There are (five) other choices that work, for example $v_3-v_1$, but not just anything will do. E.g., an invariant subspace containing $v_1$ would also contain $v_2$ and $v_3$ so it would be all of $V$. The third basis vector, in contrast, can be any of the (eighteen) vectors that are not in $V_2$.

Comment: Andreas Blass: ok, i think I see now... Thank you very much.